# Can someone help me out with some regex?

Tags: c#, regex, arrays

I'm trying to get an `int[]` from the following string. I was initially doing a `Regex().Split()` but as you can see there isn't a definite way to split this string. I could split on `[a-z]` but then I have to remove the commas afterwards. It's late and I can't think of a nice way to do this.

```
"21,false,false,25,false,false,27,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: from this example string, do you want `[21,25,27]` or `[21,0,0,25,0,0,27,0,...]` (where false = 0)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split on the following:

```
[^\d]+
```

You may get an empty element at the beginning if your string doesn't begin with a number and/or an empty element at the end if your string doesn't end with a number. If this happens you can trim those elements. Better yet, if `Regex().Split()` supports some kind of flag to not return empty strings, use that.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much. I knew I was lacking in the regex department but that was a pretty novice oversight. I had to remove the two forward slashes for some reason. What were their purpose?

Comment: @Joey Green: The forward slashes are a common delimiter for regexes in many languages (originating in perl). I guess C# (which I don't actually know) is not one of these languages. I'll remove the slashes from my answer. Please mark the answer correct.

Comment: I'm using Regex().Split() which doesn't have a constructor accepting any StringSplitOptions. I can ignore the "" elements I suppose unless you know of a better way.

Comment: I thought about that but am not sure how to use the regex in conjunction with the String.Split method.

Comment: @Joey Green: Looks like `String.Split()` can't take a regex, so disregard my suggestion about `StringSplitOptions`. I've removed that part of my answer. The point here is to be aware that you may get these empty elements at the beginning and end of your array. Make sure to deal with them somehow.

Comment: Here is an existing post regarding the removal of empty elements when using Regex().Split() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912365/c-regex-split-removing-empty-results

Comment: @Asaph Again, thank you so much. You've been extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution here is to match the string with the pattern `\d+`. 
Sometimes it is easier to split by the values you don't want to match, but here it serves as an anti-pattern.:

```
MatchCollection numbers = Regex.Matches(s, @"\d+");
```

Another solution is to use regular String.Split and some LINQ magic. First we split by commas, and then check that all letters in a given token are digits:

```
var numbers = s.Split(',').Where(word => word.All(Char.IsDigit));
```

It is an commonly ignored fact the `\d` in .Net matches **all Unicode digits**, and not just `[0-9]` (try ١٢٣ in your array, just for fun). A more robust solution is to try to parse each token according to your defined culture, and return the valid numbers. This can easily be adapted to support decimals, exponents or ethnic numeric formats:

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetIntegers(string s)
{
    CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    string[] tokens = s.Split(',');
    foreach (string token in tokens)
    {
        int number;
        if (Int32.TryParse(token, NumberStyles.Integer, culture, out number))
            yield return number;
    }
}
```