# C# Regular Expression Capturing Empty String

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a simple regular expression in C# to split a string into tokens. The problem I'm running into is that the pattern I'm using captures an empty string, which throws off my expected results. What can I do to change my regular expression so it doesn't capture an empty string?

```
var input = "ID=123&User=JohnDoe";
var pattern = "(?:id=)|(?:&user=)";
var tokens = Regex.Split(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Expected Results
// tokens[0] == "123"
// tokens[1] == "JohnDoe"

// Actual Results
// tokens[0] == ""
// tokens[1] == "123"
// tokens[2] == "JohnDoe"
```

Comment: See [Easiest way to parse “querystring” formatted data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956948/easiest-way-to-parse-querystring-formatted-data).

Comment: link doesn't answer OP - it relies on a System.Net.Http static method that doesn't exist in .NET core

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew definitely points to a better approach. Your query string would fail on semantically identical input `"User=JohnDoe&ID=123"` because of your check for an `&` in the regex. It's best not to reinvent the wheel on this one.

Comment: There several ways to fix this. 1) [Remove empty items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912365/c-sharp-regex-split-removing-empty-results), 2) Use `(?i)(?<=id=)[^&]+` to get id and `(?i)(?<=user=)[^&]+` to get user name, 3) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the comments to your OP regarding using a different approach may have merit, they don't address your specific question regarding the RegEx behavior.

I think that the reason though you're getting the regex behavior has to do with an implicit capture group (ed: or it could just be limiting the capture behavior of the first group is sufficient), but I haven't made it to the top level of the RegEx hierarchy of understanding.

Edit:

Working RegEx for the given test case:

`(?>id=)|(?:&user=)`

If none of this is to your liking, you could always tack a predicate to the tokens list:

`tokens.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can solve this problem with `Regex.Split` to be honest. One brute force way to do this is to remove every `""`:

```
var input = "ID=123&User=JohnDoe";
var pattern = "(?:id=)|(?:&user=)";
var tokens = Regex.Split(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Where(x => x != "");
```

I think you should use regex that actually captures the tokens in groups.

```
var input = "ID=123&User=JohnDoe";
var pattern = "id=(.+)&user=(.+)";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions
    .IgnoreCase);
match.Groups[1] // 123
```