# Regex Split behaviour when splitting string by variable length in C#

Tags: c#, regex

An application produces a flat file where each line represents data to be imported into another application. The type of data is irrelevant to this question, but suppose the first line is a string of numbers "0123456789" and the delimiter is a different width for each column. For example, I have to split the strings into an array of different lengths, e.g. 1,2,3,4 giving;

```
0
12
345
6789
```

The following code using Regex.Split(s,s) tests this; but can anyone explain why the string is split into 6 groups when I expected 4?

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string data = "0123456789"; 
        string splitPattern = "^";

        for(int x = 1; x < 5; ++x) {
            splitPattern += string.Format("(.{{{0}}})", x);
        }

        string[] processedData = Regex.Split(data, splitPattern);

        Console.WriteLine($"Using {splitPattern} to split {data} yields {processedData.Length} results.");
        foreach(string d in processedData) {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("[{0}]", d));
        }

    }
}
```

Running this code results in the following printed lines;

```
Using ^(.{1})(.{2})(.{3})(.{4}) to split 0123456789 yields 6 results.
[]
[0]
[12]
[345]
[6789]
[]
```

In reality the data includes text, numbers and punctuation. Also, the column lengths are not incremental, but I was stumped by the way this was split.

Links
[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4ITyy1)
[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7tTeEB/1)

**Edit**

Thanks for the answers and comments. I don't consider this to be a duplicate of [C# Regex.Split: Removing empty results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912365/c-sharp-regex-split-removing-empty-results) since the user actually edited their question to explain it was relating to their regex pattern. I understand now that the behaviour I've noticed is expected and after thinking about it, appreciate why this is so. The pattern in `Regex.Split(data, splitPattern)` kind of denotes where the delimiter should be. So if the pattern matches the start (and end), then an empty string is the result *before* (and *after*) the match.

I prefer Split over Match in this instance since it returns a simple `string[]` instead of a `Match`.

Comment: [*"If a match is found at the beginning or the end of the input string, an empty string is included at the beginning or the end of the returned array."*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Split_System_String_System_String_)

Comment: Looks like you actually wanted `Regex.Match` with the pattern, not `Regex.Split`, see https://ideone.com/8tuw6k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Split actually splits the results into a component before and after the expression. When the expression has groups in it, it also includes it as part of the split as well.

See tweaked demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gUnxGP

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string data = "01234,56789";

        var splitPattern = ","; // two results

        string[] processedData = Regex.Split(data, splitPattern);
        Console.WriteLine($"Using {splitPattern} to split {data} yields {processedData.Length} results.");
        foreach (string d in processedData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("[{0}]", d));
        }

        splitPattern = "(,)"; // three results (includes the comma itself)

        processedData = Regex.Split(data, splitPattern);
        Console.WriteLine($"Using {splitPattern} to split {data} yields {processedData.Length} results.");
        foreach (string d in processedData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("[{0}]", d));
        }
    }
}

/* Output
Using , to split 01234,56789 yields 2 results.
[01234]
[56789]
Using (,) to split 01234,56789 yields 3 results.
[01234]
[,]
[56789]
*/
```

As Wiktor commented, you probably should be using Matches instead of Split

Comment: The group thing is interesting but not completely right. I've altered your [demo again](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QauzQm) splitting on ,01234,56789, which is interesting. I'm still unsure of the purpose of adding an empty string at the start and end? Also with regards to Regex.Match vs Regex.Split, would Split perform better for longer text? The real life data is approx 50 differently sized columns over 840 characters.

Comment: That's the expected behavior, as there is an empty string before the first comma and after the last comma. Splitting a string of `",,"` by `,` would return three empty strings... as I would expect. FWIW, JavaScript has the same behavior.

Comment: WRT Split versus Match, I wouldn't worry about performance until it becomes a problem. I couldn't comment on performance without testing it myself... which I haven't