# Regex Split help required

Tags: c#, regex

Regex to split
CustomerID, PaymentAmount, Date, EmailDateFourDays, RefNo

CustomerID
PaymentAmount
Date
EmailDateFourDays
RefNo

```
Regex.Split(fieldValue, "[\\s;,]" , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

I am getting empty value
[image]

Comment: Also: would [`string.Split(Char[], StringSplitOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0#system-string-split(system-char()-system-stringsplitoptions)) be an option? ==> [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XurPKJ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912694/4394841), you can simply filter it out by:

```
var result = Regex.Split(fieldValue, "[\s;,]" , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
     .Where(s => s != String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Where()` to remove all empty elements,

```
var result = Regex.Split(fieldValue, "[\\s;,]" , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
     .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)) //Filter non empty strings
     .ToList() //Convert to list
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Fiddle, I tested this to work on (what I assume to be) your input:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = 
@"CustomerID
PaymentAmount
Date
EmailDateFourDays
RefNo";
        
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|",input.Split(new char[]{' ', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)));
    }
}
```

**It's not Regex** but produces the output:

```
CustomerID|PaymentAmount|Date|EmailDateFourDays|RefNo
```

which indicates, all fields have been found and empty ones removed.